# Binary operations

Tags: linear-algebra

**STATEMENT:** Define an equivalence relation on the set of operators $\mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T_1\sim T_2$ iff $\exists S\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ $T_1\circ S=S\circ T_2$, where $T_1,T_2\in\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Show that there isn't a binary operation $+: (\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)/\sim) \times(\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)/\sim)\rightarrow (\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)/\sim) 
$ such that $[T_1]+[T_2]=[T_1+T_2]$.

**QUESTION:** I don't see a simple way of showing that no such binary operation exists. I attempted a proof by contradiction by assuming such a binary operation exists, but I can't seem to find the contradiction that I need. Please offer some hints as to what I should be searching for.

Comment: Nevermind I found the solution. I was just interpreting the problem incorrectly. I will post an answer in a little bit.